# socket connect() vs bind()

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Both `connect()` and `bind()` system calls 'associate' the socket file descriptor to an address (typically an ip/port combination). Their prototypes are like:-

```
int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,
               socklen_t addrlen);
```

and

```
int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,
            socklen_t addrlen);
```

What is the exact difference between 2 calls? When should one use `connect()` and when `bind()`?

Specifically, in some sample server client codes, found that client is using `connect()` and server is using the `bind()` call. Reason was not fully clear to me.

Comment: In one sentence: bind is to local address, connect is to remote address.

Answer (score 307, accepted):

To make understanding better , lets find out where exactly bind and connect comes into picture,

[image]

Further to positioning of two calls , as clarified by Sourav,

bind() associates the socket with its local address [that's why server side binds, so that clients can use that address to connect to server.]
connect() is used to connect to a remote [server] address, that's why is client side, connect [read as: connect to server] is used.

We cannot use them interchangeably (even when we have client/server on same machine) because of specific roles and corresponding implementation.

I will further recommend to correlate these calls TCP/IP handshake .

[image]

So, who will send SYN here, it will be `connect()`. While `bind()` is used for defining the communication end point.

Comment: thanks bro. With the diagram everything can unstand fastly. Can you tell what is the difference here, If we are using udp?

Comment: accept()  <br>  
should be moved below  <br>  
block until connection from client

Comment: i think all nodes in a network in a p2p network should use  bind, am i correct?

Answer (score 59):

**The one liner :** `bind()` to own address, `connect()` to remote address.

Quoting from the man page of [`bind()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind)

> bind() assigns the address specified by addr to the socket referred to by the file descriptor sockfd. addrlen specifies the size, in bytes, of the address structure pointed to by addr. Traditionally, this operation is called "assigning a name to a socket".

and, from the same for [`connect()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect)

> The connect() system call connects the socket referred to by the file descriptor sockfd to the address specified by addr.

To clarify,

- `bind()` associates the socket with its local address [that's why
  server side `bind`s, so that clients can use that address to connect
  to server.]
- `connect()` is used to connect to a remote [server] address, that's
  why is client side, connect [read as: connect to server] is used.

Comment: So, say, if both server and client process run on same machine, can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: @SiddharthaGhosh No. maybe client and server are on same machine, but still they **are** different process, right? Both the API servs its own puprpose. They are never `interchangeable`

Comment: What is exactly meant by local and remote in this context?

Comment: @SiddharthaGhosh `local` -> the process itself, `remote` --> the other process.

Comment: @SouravGhosh so this means I can't specify a port to bind  to at client side ?

Comment: @HengqiChen You can, but usually, you don't need to. It's best to leave it to your OS to allocate the port for your application, when as a client, you are reaching out to the server.

Answer (score 23):

I think it would help your comprehension if you think of `connect()` and `listen()` as counterparts, rather than `connect()` and `bind()`. The reason for this is that you can call or omit `bind()` before either, although it's rarely a good idea to call it before `connect()`, or not to call it before `listen()`.

If it helps to think in terms of servers and clients, it is `listen()` which is the hallmark of the former, and `connect()` the latter. `bind()` can be found - or not found - on either.

If we assume our server and client are on different machines, it becomes easier to understand the various functions.

`bind()` acts locally, which is to say it binds the end of the connection on the machine on which it is called, to the requested address and assigns the requested port to you. It does that irrespective of whether that machine will be a client or a server. `connect()` initiates a connection to a server, which is to say it connects to the requested address and port on the server, from a client. That server will almost certainly have called `bind()` prior to `listen()`, in order for you to be able to know on which address and port to connect to it with using `connect()`.

If you don't call `bind()`, a port and address will be implicitly assigned and bound on the local machine for you when you call either `connect()` (client) or `listen()` (server). However, that's a side effect of both, not their purpose. A port assigned in this manner is ephemeral.

An important point here is that the client does not need to be bound, because clients connect to servers, and so the server will know the address and port of the client even though you are using an ephemeral port, rather than binding to something specific. On the other hand, although the server could call `listen()` without calling `bind()`, in that scenario they would need to discover their assigned ephemeral port, and communicate that to any client that it wants to connect to it.

I assume as you mention `connect()` you're interested in TCP, but this also carries over to UDP, where not calling `bind()` before the first `sendto()` (UDP is connection-less) also causes a port and address to be implicitly assigned and bound. One function you cannot call without binding is `recvfrom()`, which will return an error, because without an assigned port and bound address, there is nothing to receive from (or too much, depending on how you interpret the absence of a binding).

Answer (score 20):

bind tells the running process to claim a port. i.e, it should bind itself to port 80 and listen for incomming requests. with bind, your process becomes a server. when you use connect, you tell your process to connect to a port that is ALREADY in use. your process becomes a client. the difference is important: bind wants a port that is not in use (so that it can claim it and become a server), and connect wants a port that is already in use (so it can connect to it and talk to the server)

Answer (score 11):

From Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#bind.28.29

**connect():**

The connect() system call connects a socket, identified by its file descriptor, to a remote host specified by that host's address in the argument list.

Certain types of sockets are connectionless, most commonly user datagram protocol sockets. For these sockets, connect takes on a special meaning: the default target for sending and receiving data gets set to the given address, allowing the use of functions such as send() and recv() on connectionless sockets.

connect() returns an integer representing the error code: 0 represents success, while -1 represents an error.

**bind():**

bind() assigns a socket to an address. When a socket is created using socket(), it is only given a protocol family, but not assigned an address. This association with an address must be performed with the bind() system call before the socket can accept connections to other hosts. bind() takes three arguments:

sockfd, a descriptor representing the socket to perform the bind on.
my_addr, a pointer to a sockaddr structure representing the address to bind to.
addrlen, a socklen_t field specifying the size of the sockaddr structure.
Bind() returns 0 on success and -1 if an error occurs.

Examples:
1.)Using Connect

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  int clientSocket;
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  socklen_t addr_size;

  /*---- Create the socket. The three arguments are: ----*/
  /* 1) Internet domain 2) Stream socket 3) Default protocol (TCP in this case) */
  clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  /*---- Configure settings of the server address struct ----*/
  /* Address family = Internet */
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  /* Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order */
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);
  /* Set the IP address to desired host to connect to */
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.17");
  /* Set all bits of the padding field to 0 */
  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

  /*---- Connect the socket to the server using the address struct ----*/
  addr_size = sizeof serverAddr;
  connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, addr_size);

  /*---- Read the message from the server into the buffer ----*/
  recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);

  /*---- Print the received message ----*/
  printf("Data received: %s",buffer);   

  return 0;
}
```

2.)Bind Example:

```
int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in source, destination = {};  //two sockets declared as previously
    int sock = 0;
    int datalen = 0;
    int pkt = 0;

    uint8_t *send_buffer, *recv_buffer;

    struct sockaddr_storage fromAddr;   // same as the previous entity struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
    unsigned int addrlen;  //in the previous example socklen_t addr_size;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 3;  /* 3 Seconds Time-out */
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    /* creating the socket */         
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) 
        printf("Failed to create socket\n");

    /*set the socket options*/
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));

    /*Inititalize source to zero*/
    memset(&source, 0, sizeof(source));       //source is an instance of sockaddr_in. Initialization to zero
    /*Inititalize destinaton to zero*/
    memset(&destination, 0, sizeof(destination));


    /*---- Configure settings of the source address struct, WHERE THE PACKET IS COMING FROM ----*/
    /* Address family = Internet */
    source.sin_family = AF_INET;    
    /* Set IP address to localhost */   
    source.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;  //INADDR_ANY = 0.0.0.0
    /* Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order */
    source.sin_port = htons(7005); 
    /* Set all bits of the padding field to 0 */
    memset(source.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof source.sin_zero); //optional


    /*bind socket to the source WHERE THE PACKET IS COMING FROM*/
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &source, sizeof(source)) < 0) 
        printf("Failed to bind socket");

    /* setting the destination, i.e our OWN IP ADDRESS AND PORT */
    destination.sin_family = AF_INET;                 
    destination.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");  
    destination.sin_port = htons(7005); 

    //Creating a Buffer;
    send_buffer=(uint8_t *) malloc(350);
    recv_buffer=(uint8_t *) malloc(250);

    addrlen=sizeof(fromAddr);

    memset((void *) recv_buffer, 0, 250);
    memset((void *) send_buffer, 0, 350);

    sendto(sock, send_buffer, 20, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &destination, sizeof(destination));

    pkt=recvfrom(sock, recv_buffer, 98,0,(struct sockaddr *)&destination, &addrlen);
    if(pkt > 0)
        printf("%u bytes received\n", pkt);
    }
```

I hope that clarifies the difference

Please note that the socket type that you declare will depend on what you require, this is extremely important

Answer (score 3):

Too Long; Don't Read: The difference is whether the source (local) or the destination address/port is being set. In short, `bind()` set the source and `connect()` set the destination. Regardless of TCP or UDP.

## `bind()`

`bind()` set the socket's local (source) address. This is the address where packets are received. Packets sent by the socket carry this as the source address, so the other host will know where to send back its packets.

If receive is not needed the socket source address is useless. Protocols like TCP require receiving enabled in order to send properly, as the destination host send back a confirmation when one or more packets have arrived (i.e. acknowledgement).

## `connect()`

- TCP has a "connected" state. `connect()` triggers the TCP code to try to establish a connection to the other side.
- UDP has no "connected" state. `connect()` only set a default address to where packets are sent when no address is specified. When `connect()` is not used, `sendto()` or `sendmsg()` must be used containing the destination address.

When `connect()` or a send function is called, and no address is bound, Linux automatically bind the socket to a random port. For technical details, take a look at [`inet_autobind()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/inet_autobind) in Linux kernel source code.

## Side notes

- `listen()` is TCP only.
- In *AF_INET* family, the socket's source or destination address (`struct sockaddr_in`) is composed by an IP address (see [IP header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.1)), and TCP or UDP port (see [TCP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.1) and [UDP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768) header).