# What IP address should be used in a client server program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, network-programming

I am trying to build a small peer to peer messaging application which uses a basic client server system in python.

In case of client, we use :-

```
s.connect(('ip_address', port))
```

While testing the program, with client program running on my tablet & server program running on my laptop & both my laptop and my tablet is connected to internet through WiFi Hotspot of my phone & when I am using gethostaddr() then both the tablet & laptop are showing 127.0.0.1.

Which ip_address should I use for both client & server?

Note :- I am really confused & a novice. Please help me out.

Comment: The `127.0.0.1` address is the Loopback address, and anything sent to that address immediately loops back inside the sending host, never leaving the host. Addresses in the `127.0.0.0/8` network can never be seen outside a host, on any network, anywhere. Loopback addresses are useful for testing in a single device, but you cannot use them on an actual network.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the ip addresses for your wireless adapter. 127.0.0.1 is a loopback ip referring to yourself which won't work. To find your ip address, use ifconfig (on linux) or ipconfig (for windows) and check for ip address in front of a wireless adapter named something like wlan0

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014955/socket-connect-vs-bind) for better understanding of connect and bind

for connect(), you should use server address.
run command `ifconfig` on both of your machines, the wifi interface description will give you their appropriate addresses for your local wifi network.