# Reconnect to server python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to connect a client to a serverr. After I connect I want to check do some sort of validation. (checking if I got the massage 'ready') and if not, try to connect again until the server will send 'ready' and not something else.

```py
tcp_sock = socket.socket()
tcp_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcp_sock.bind(('', 7865))

connected = False
while not connected:
    tcp_sock.connect(('192.168.0.111', 7865))

    if tcp_sock.recv(1024) == b'ready':
        connected = True
    else:
       tcp_sock.close()
```

if I put `tcp_sock.close()` after the else, I get this error when connecting again: `an operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`.

if I put `pass` instead of `tcp_sock.close()` (do not close the socket) I get this error when connecting again: `Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted`.

PS. It works without errors without the `tcp_sock.bind(('', 7865))` but I have to bind the client to a specific port (here 7865) and I'm using `tcp_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` to be able to reconnect again with the server.

How can I reconnect to the server without getting an error?

Comment: `but I have to bind the client to a specific port (here 7865)` why ?

Comment: @ShellCode I want the client to use port 7865 (I want the whole program to use port 7865) so I can say it runs on port 7865

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call `bind()` on the client code.

Comment: This may help about where to use bind https://stackoverflow.com/a/27017691/13548379

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it correctly but I would suggest you use normal receiveing methods as it'll be easier for python to send and receive data.

CLIENT.py

```
import socket
import sys
import select

my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.connect(("__YOUR_IP__",7865)) #IMPORTANT
sys.stdout.write('your message: ')
sys.stdout.flush()
while True:
   #...
    else:
        data = my_socket.recv(1024)
        print "data" , data
```

Comment: Oh my bad I meant a regular receive, I still tho want to bind the socket as I said in my question, and it doesnt work because of that.

Comment: I dont think you understood my question correctly

Answer (score 0):

If a TCP connection is not successful connect will throw an error. So handling exceptions from connect method should be enough to check if you are connected.

But if you want to fix this way; your close method also releases the socket therefore you need to define tcp-connect again in the  while loop.

Comment: _If a TCP connection is not successful connect will throw an error._ It _does_ connect successfuly, see my code... I also tried to define tcp_socket again in the while loop but still same error

Comment: I meant that you do not need another mechanism to check connection