# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument python socket connection problem

Tags: python, sockets

Currently am creating TCP socket to send and receive data for a backend app but am facing `self.socket.connect(("localhost", 8000)) OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` error... have looked up similar errors on here along with other forums and has something to do with me placing `self.socket.connect(("localhost", 8000))` within the other indented code in the `start_client` function but when I try to place it elsewhere within the file I'm either getting self is not defined or invalid argument for `socket_connect`

Here's my ClientServer.py code:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096

class ClientServer(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Client Server started w/ new threads...")
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = None

    def send_to_Server(self, data):
        print('Time to send data to Server..... %s', data)
        self.socket.send(data.encode("utf8"))   

    def receive_from_Server(self):
        print('Time to receive from Server.....')
        result_bytes = self.socket.recv(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)
        result_string = result_bytes.decode("utf8")
        print("Result from server is {}".format(result_string))

    def start_client(self):
        # Creates TCP socket
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # Re-uses socket
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        # Binds socket to host and port
        self.socket.bind(("localhost", 8000))
        # Connects socket to host and port
        self.socket.connect(("localhost", 8000))
        print('Client connected....')
        threads = [] 


    def connect_client(self):
        
        while True:
            # Become a server socket
            self.socket.listen(5)
            self.__clients = {}

            # Starts connection
            (clientSocket, client_address) = self.socket.accept()
            newthread = ClientServer("localhost", 8000)
            newthread.start
            threads.append(newthread)

            for t in threads:
                t.join()


            

cs = ClientServer()

cs.start_client()
cs.connect_client()
cs.send_to_Server('Hello')
cs.receive_from_Server()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socket.bind` is used by a server to start offering services.  `socket connect` is used by the client.  If this is just supposed to be the client, then delete the `bind` call.  Check the chart here:

[socket connect() vs bind()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014955/socket-connect-vs-bind)

In that case, your class name is probably not appropriate.